# Docker-Compose HAProxy missing frontend

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, haproxy

I'm trying to use HAProxy as a loadbalancer for my python webapp which uses redis. I'm working on transitioning the docker run commands to docker-compose using the docker-compose.yml --but I'm running into issues

**Below is my current "docker run" commands, which works perfectly fine!**

```
docker run --name sdnapi-redis -v /opt/redis:/data -p 6379:6379 -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
docker run -d --name sdnapi1 --link sdnapi-redis:redis mycomp/sdnapi
docker run -d --name sdnapi2 --link sdnapi-redis:redis mycomp/sdnapi
docker run -d --name sdnapilb -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 1936:1936 -e DEFAULT_SSL_CERT="$(awk 1 ORS='\\n' ./certs/cert.pem)" -v /certs/:/certs/ --link sdnapi1:sdnapi1 --link sdnapi2:sdnapi2 dockercloud/haproxy
```

**Here is my docker-compose.yml that should replicate the same functionality**

```
version: '2'
services:
  sdnapi:
    image: mycomp/sdnapi
    links:
      - sdnapi-redis:redis
  sdnapilb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy:1.2.1
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_SSL_CERT
    volumes:
      - /certs/:/certs/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "1936:1936"
    links:
      - sdnapi:sdnapi
  sdnapi-redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - /opt/redis:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

When I run the docker run commands, this is the sdnapilb logs:

```
  global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  log-send-hostname
  maxconn 4096
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stats level admin
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
defaults
  balance roundrobin
  log global
  mode http
  option redispatch
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000
listen stats
  bind :1936
  mode http
  stats enable
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 1m
  timeout server 1m
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /
  stats auth stats:stats
frontend default_frontend
  bind :80
  bind :443 ssl crt /certs/
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  maxconn 4096
  defcon 1
  default_backend default_service
```

When I run the docker-compose.yml with "docker-compose up -d".. I lose the *frontend* section.

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  log-send-hostname
  maxconn 4096
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stats level admin
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
defaults
  balance roundrobin
  log global
  mode http
  option redispatch
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000
listen stats
  bind :1936
  mode http
  stats enable
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 1m
  timeout server 1m
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /
  stats auth stats:stats
```

Can you see any issues with either setup? I want to use docker-compose for its ability to scale.

Comment: try running it without -d so you can see the output in your terminal. that will help you debug, then post the error along with your question

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried that, but there's not much in the logs besides the haproxy.cfg output which is missing the frontend section. The stats page (port 1936) works fine, but since the frontend is missing, there's no exposure on port 80 or 443

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue...

The docker-compose.yml has issues with the links.. the format for links is *service name*:*alias*

The issue with mine is that even though my service names were correct, **the alias' were incorrect**... causing the docker-compose to fail without an actual error. Since the alias doesn't exist, it just doesn't link the container -thus no frontend